# Update changes made in datagridview into Access 2016

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, datagridview

I made a connection with an Access database (Access 2016) using `dataset`, `bindingsource`, `tableadapter`, `bindingnavigator`, and `datagridview`.

It works, I can navigate in the `datagridview`, make changes, add and delete records in the `datagridview`, but these changes don't appear in the Access DB.

Data is loaded with:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'FacturatieDataSet.Catalogus' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    CatalogusTableAdapter.Fill(FacturatieDataSet.Catalogus
End Sub
```

For deleting I use:

```
Private Sub BindingNavigatorDeleteItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BindingNavigatorDeleteItem.Click
    CatalogusBindingSource.RemoveCurrent()
    CatalogusTableAdapter.Update(FacturatieDataSet.Catalogus)
End Sub
```

I'm new with VB 2015, I'm not a programmer, I do this for personnal study.

What is an (easy) solution to my problem?

Answer (score 0):

You fill the datagridview but you don't update it (except when you delete a record).

Look up a tutorial on how to handle basic CRUD operations with a datagridview.